# vba excel internet explorer disable warning https message

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

when loading a website , i get the following Security warning :

**do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely.**

This popup cause my code to go to error , is there a way to disable it with vba ?

Thanks.

here is the code

```
    Sub Start()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument


ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://mywebsite.com")
ie.FullScreen = True
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set doc = ie.document



doc.getElementById("navMenu2").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

The [reason](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx) for the warning is that you’re on an SSL-secured (https protocol) page that is attempting to load non-SSL (http protocol) content.

The best ways to fix this is to either:

1. Visit your website with http instead of https - `ie.navigate ("http://mywebsite.com")`
2. Fix the security issues in your website (do not load unsecure content when visiting with https)

If you just want to fix it for testing purposes, you can [change the settings in your test browser](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/security-warning-do-you-want-to-view-only-the-web/e7526a5f-f953-4235-90c3-004f9b973585):

> 1. Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
> 2. Select the "Security" tab -> Click the "Custom Level" button
> 3. In the "Miscellaneous" section change “Display mixed content” to Enable.